# How to validate text input so that it only allows a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ();:?!,.[]{}- characters(also space) and in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

How to validate text input so that it only allows `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, ();:?!,.[]{}-` characters(also space)?

I added something like in my model

```
class Oder < ApplicationRecord
   ......
   ......
   validates :text, presence: true, format: { with: /[0-9\w]*[\(\;\:\-\?\!\,\.\[\]\{\}\,\.)]*/ }
   ......
 end
end
```

But it is not working. It allows other characters(wïth ûmlauts) also.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this one `format: { with:  /\A[A-Z0-9, ();:?!,.[]{}-]+\z/}`

Comment: Seems the regex is invalid! it is showing `premature end of char-class: /\A[A-Z0-9, ();:?!,.[]{}-]+\z/` error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the regexp matches when one or more characters are in your text somewhere. You need to change the regexp to only match when the characters are the only characters between the start of the string (`\A`) and its end (`\z`).

Change your regexp to:

```
/\A[0-9\w\s\(\;\:\-\?\!\,\.\[\]\{\}\,\.)]*\z/
```

Comment: It is not allowing `bla bla` text also. Showing invalid validation error

Comment: @SimpleLime you are correct. I did not mention that it should allow space. I updated the question. thanks

Comment: @JunanChakma: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :text, without: /[-0-9\w ;:,.?!\[\]{}()]*/
```

Comment: It is showing validation error after submit `bla bla` as input. I should not show any validation error for this input. but for `test wïth ûmlauts` input it should show validation error.